# ¿Cómo hago la suma algebraica de varios terminos elevados a una serie fibonnaci con un for?

Tags: c, bucle-for

He intentado esto, la segunda función solo la utilizo para mostrar en pantalla la secuencia que lleva el ejercicio pero quisiera saber como puedo hacer la suma algebraica de dichos términos.
He intentado hacer la suma mediante un `for` pero no me da el resultado que necesito, La secuencia que debo calcular es esta `+ (1/3)^1 - (3/9)^2 + (5/15)^3 + (7/21)^5 - (9/27)^8`
**Gracias de antemano**

```c
int ingresolimite();
void generadorTerminos(int limite);
int calculoSerie(int limite);
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int limite;
    limite = ingresolimite();
    generadorTerminos(limite);
    calculoSerie(limite);
    return 0;
}
int ingresolimite()
{
    int dato;
    printf("Ingrese el limite de la serie\n");
    scanf("%d", &dato);
    getchar();
    return dato;
}
void generadorTerminos(int limite)
{
    float numerador = 1;
    float denominador = 3;
    float x = 0, y = 1, exponente;
    for (int i = 1; i <= limite; i++)
    {
        exponente = x + y;
        x = y;
        y = exponente;
        if ((int)exponente % 2 == 0)
        {
            printf(" - (%.0f/%.0f)^%.0f", numerador, denominador, exponente);
        }
        else
        {
            printf(" + (%.0f/%.0f)^%.0f", numerador, denominador, exponente);
        }
        numerador = numerador + 2;
        denominador = denominador + 6;
    }
}
int calculoSerie(int limite){
    float resultado;
    int x = 0, y = 1, exponente;
    float a = 0.33;
    for (int i = 1; i <= limite; i++)
    {
        exponente = x + y;
        x = y;
        y = exponente;
        resultado = pow(a, exponente);
        if (exponente%2==0)
        {
            resultado= resultado-resultado;
        }else
        {
            resultado = resultado+resultado;
        }
        printf("%.2f", resultado);
    }
    return resultado;      
}
'''
```

Answer (score 0):

Tienes varios errores en el código.

El primero y más obvio es que esta expresión tiene que estar mal:

```
resultado= resultado-resultado;
```

pues sea cual sea el valor de `resultado`, el lado derecho dará necesariamente cero al estar restando un valor a sí mismo. Seguro que no era eso lo que querías hacer, y es que estás usando una sola variable (`resultado`) para dos cosas diferentes: para almacenar el total acumulado de la suma de la serie, y para recoger el valor de uno de sus términos. Necesitas dos variables separadas para ello.

Además el cálculo del término no es muy exacto, pues lo calculas como `pow(a, exponente)`, pero el valor de `a` lo has fijado a 0.33, que es un redondeo un poco demasiado basto. Mejor calcúlalo como 1/3.0.

Debes asegurarte de inicializar todas las variables antes de usarlas, en particular la variable `resultado` que irá guardando la suma de los términos a medida que iteres, que debe ser inicializada con 0.

Finalmente la función `calculoSerie()` debe retornar `float` y no `int` como habías declarado.

Además de esto, la función `generadorTerminos()` y la función `calculoSerie()` comparten mucho código. De hecho es casi todo igual (ambas necesitan `numerador`, `denominador`, `exponente`, e iterar por el mismo bucle) y solo cambia qué hacen con los números que van obteniendo. La primera se limita a imprimirlos en forma de fórmula, la segunda en cambio ha realmente la operación para computar el término y añadirlo al resultado.

Por tanto, para evitar replicar código, unificaré ambas cosas en una sola función. En cada iteración del bucle se imprimirá la fórmula del término y *además* se computará y añadirá al resultado.

Mi código por tanto sería este:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

int ingresolimite();
float calculoSerie(int limite);

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int limite;
    float resultado;
    limite = ingresolimite();
    resultado = calculoSerie(limite);
    printf(" = %.5f\n", resultado);
    return 0;
}

int ingresolimite()
{
    int dato;
    printf("Ingrese el limite de la serie\n");
    scanf("%d", &dato);
    getchar();
    return dato;
}

float calculoSerie(int limite){
    float resultado=0, termino=0, a=1/3.0;
    int x = 0, y = 1, exponente;
    float numerador = 1;
    float denominador = 3;
    for (int i = 1; i <= limite; i++)
    {
        exponente = x + y;
        x = y;
        y = exponente;
        termino = pow(a, exponente);
        if (exponente%2==0)
        {
            printf(" - (%.0f/%.0f)^%d", numerador, denominador, exponente);
            resultado = resultado-termino;
        }else
        {
            printf(" + (%.0f/%.0f)^%d", numerador, denominador, exponente);
            resultado = resultado+termino;
        }
        numerador = numerador + 2;
        denominador = denominador + 6;
    }
    return resultado;
}
```

Ejemplo de ejecución:

```
Ingrese el limite de la serie
5

 + (1/3)^1 - (3/9)^2 + (5/15)^3 + (7/21)^5 - (9/27)^8 = 0.26322
```